# The difference between smote.fit_sample() and smote.fit_resample()

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, imblearn

In [imblearn](/questions/tagged/imblearn), what is the difference between `smote.fit_sample()` and `smote.fit_resample()`, and when should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

`fit_sample` was replaced with `fit_resample`.
[Changelog v0.4](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-4)

Based on the [diff](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/pull/462/files#diff-419cc9026ee190eef0f54121e94c2b44c7aa8b911d3317c10e05717e62d1a2a9R96), specifically: `fit_sample = fit_resample`; it looks like `fit_resample` should be backward compatible to work in place of `fit_sample`